# Sending from SAP Private Domain in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sap, sender-authentication-package

- Would it be possible to send from the SAP verified private domain @company.com in Marketing Cloud without disrupting internal company correspondence that uses the same domain? I have seen conflicting opinions on this and would appreciate any clarification.

Originally, we set up a SAP verified domain which is: @company-email.com. We would like to switch this SAP verified domain from @company-email.com to our company domain @company.com and host the DNS ourselves. We no longer have any use for our original SAP verified domain.

Furthermore, according to this article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333591&type=1&mode=1, there is a difference between a Private Domain that is included with the Sender Authentication Package vs. a Private Domain that is purchased separately. We do not wish to purchase a private domain separately. We wish to switch the current SAP domain @company-email.com to @company.com.

Also, we have no need for RMM and would prefer if replies went directly to user@company.com

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot *change* your SAP domain to a new one, once it's been assigned it's there.

This is also stated clearly in the documentation - [**Marketing Cloud SAP**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_sap.htm&type=5):

> To change an SAP domain, the purchase of a new SAP package is
>   required. The existing Dedicated IP remains in place.

For your first question - yes, absolutely.

Majority of businesses using SFMC probably use their original company domain to send out messages.
Over here it doesn't matter if the domain is purchased via SAP or Private Domain, once properly configured (DKIM, SPF, DomainKeys, SenderID etc), it is shared and used by SFMC and other platforms without problems.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification.